# why my code is not logging when my value is < 0.5?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

why my code is not logging when my value is < 0.5? i am trying to log something when animation is completed that handlePressIn animation when the animation is fully completed how can I log it?

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Animated } from 'react-native';
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';

const App = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [scaleValue, setScaleValue] = useState(new Animated.Value(1));

  const handlePressIn = () => {
    Animated.spring(scaleValue, {
      toValue: 0.8,
      useNativeDriver: true
    }).start();
  };

  scaleValue.addListener(({ value }) => {
    // Check if the scale value is less than 0.5 (when the circle becomes small)
    if (value < 0.5) {
      console.log('Circle is small!');
    }
  });

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
          borderRadius: 150,
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          transform: [{ scale: scaleValue }],
        }}
        onPress={handlePressIn}
      >
        <Text>Press me!</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}

export default App

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not logging anything because the `scaleValue` is never < 0.5.
You initially set it to be 1, and inside the `handlePressIn` you animate it from 1 to 0.8. It will log when you set it to be 0.3 in the `handlePressIn`.

Also for the animation to work, you need to create an Animated component like this.

```
const AnimatedTouchable = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(TouchableOpacity);
```

You can try out these changes here: https://snack.expo.dev/@viljarremato/blissful-pastry

Comment: Thanks it works goods but it lags so bad